# Aster DEM indexing open-data-cube, Cube in a box

Tags: dem, aster, open-data-cube

I am working on Cube-in-a-box, local installation, and want to index Terra Aster DEM data. If anyone has worked on these, can someone share the preparation & indexing script or guide me for the same?

Comment: Can you please point to the source of the data you're hoping to index?

Comment: I am trying to follow this https://github.com/ceos-seo/data_cube_notebooks/blob/master/notebooks/vegetation/forests/Forest_Change_VNSC.ipynb, and for that I am trying to index and source is https://search.earthdata.nasa.gov/search?fi=ASTER, any other source can also do.

Comment: Ok, give me a little time and I'll see if I can write something up.